# Why can you not create sublclasses of PySide6.QtCore.Signal?

Tags: python, subclass, pyside6, qtcore

I am working on a project where I need to activate a callback every time a signal is emitted. To achieve this, I created a custom subclass of `PySide6.QtCore.Signal`. The `CallbackSignal` class is designed to emit the signal and execute a callback function with the emitted value.

```py
class CallbackSignal(Signal):
    """QT Signal that is emitted with a callback"""

    def __init__(self, returnType: object, callback: Callable):
        super().__init__(returnType)
        self.callback = callback

    def emit(self, val: any):
        super().emit(val)
        if self.callback:
            self.callback(val)
```

However, when I run the program, I encounter the following error:

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  ...
TypeError: type 'PySide6.QtCore.Signal' is not an acceptable base type
```

My question is: **Why am I unable to create a subclass of `PySide6.QtCore.Signal`?** Is there is a specific reason for this limitation? If so, what are some alternative solutions to achieve this functionality?

I am open to any suggestions or insights that can help me overcome this. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Why don't you just connect the signal to the callback?

Comment: Strictly speaking, (at least in CPython) every class has a flag that indicates whether you can subclass it or not. What makes a class unsuitable for subclassing, requiring a way to disable subclassing, is the question.

Comment: Signals are not simple standard python objects: they are unbound objects that become actual bound signals whenever they are referenced as instance attributes. Besides, what would be the point of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mahkitah I realized I can just connect to the signal:

```py
class Controller(QObject):
    callbackSignal = Signal()

    def __init__(callback: Callable):
        super().__init__()
        self.callbackSignal.connect(callback)
```

Now any time the `callbackSignal` signal is emitted the `callback` method is also activated with the same value.